# What are exact inputs and their dimension for Decoder part of the transformers?

Tags: transformers

In the [Illustrated transformer article](http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/)  from Jay Alamar, in the decoder side paragraph, he says

> The encoder starts by processing the input sequence. The output of the top encoder is then transformed into a set of attention vectors K and V.

What I understand, the output of the encoder is a matrix (Number of words x Embedding Length). So where those K and V come from?
What is the dimension of this K and V? Can someone please explain the exact input and its dimension for Decoder ?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: dimensions of $K$ and $V$ are $(seq\_len \times d_k)$ and $(seq\_len \times d_v)$ respectively. $d_k$ and $d_v$ are parameters, but they are often taken as $d_k=d\_model/nheads$ and $d_v=d_k$

Long answer: I think you are mixing up two concepts here: the dimensions of K/V in the attention calculation and the dimensions of the Decoder. Let's walk through the dimensions of the calculation of self-attention first. This is given by
$$
softmax(\frac{Q^TK}{\sqrt{d_k}})\cdot V
$$
Going a bit into the details, our input sequence $X$ has dimensions $seq\_len \times d\_model$. $X$ is multiplied by weight matrices $W^Q$, $W^K$, and $W^V$ with dimensions $(d\_model\times d_k)$, $(d\_model\times d_k)$, and $(d\_model\times d_v)$ respectively. Therefore, the matrices $Q$ and $K$ have dimensions $(seq\_len \times d_k)$ and the V matrix has dimensions $(seq\_len \times d_v)$.

The overall dimensions from the attention calculation has dimensions $seq\_len \times d_v$. However, we multiply this by a final weight matrix, $W^0$ with dimensions $(d_v \times d\_model)$. This final step returns us to the original dimensions of $(seq\_len\times d\_model)$.

Now for the decoder, our input, $X$ is a sequence of another length, say $seq\_len2$. However, our key and value matrices which we compare to are still from the encoder. Then our $Q$, $K$, and $V$ matrices now have dimensions $(seq\_len2 \times d_k)$, $(seq\_len \times d_k)$, $(seq\_len \times d_v)$. Walking through the same calculations give the decoder output to have dimensions $(seq\_len2 \times d\_model)$.

Comment: One minor correction: it should be $Q K^T$, otherwise the dimensions don't work out.